# How to change date format from date picker(calendar view)

Tags: android, calendar, format, calendarview

I'm newbie android developer.

Now, I'm try to change date format from m/d/yyyy to mmddyyyy.

This is refer link :http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-calendarview.html

Hope to someone help me.

Sorry for my bad English language.

myCalendarView.java

```html
package com.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class myCalendarView  extends Activity {
 
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CalendarView calendar = new CalendarView(this);
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(mDateSetListener);
        setContentView(calendar);

    }

    // the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
    private CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener mDateSetListener =
        new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, 
                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            String selectedDate = new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
            .append(mYear).append(" ").toString();

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("dateSelected", selectedDate);

            //Add the set of extended data to the intent and start it
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtras(b);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);       
            finish();
        }
    };

}
```

MainActivity.java

```html
package com.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
    private EditText editT1;
    private Button btn1;

    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int CALENDAR_VIEW_ID = 1;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       
        
        // editText1
        editT1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        
        // button1
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // add a click listener to the button
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myCalendarView.class); 
                startActivityForResult(intent,CALENDAR_VIEW_ID); 
            }
        });
        
        // get the current date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // display the current date
        updateCurrentDate();
  
    }

    // updates the date we display in the TextView
    private void updateCurrentDate() {
     editT1.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
    
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch(requestCode) {
        case CALENDAR_VIEW_ID: 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                editT1.setText(bundle.getString("dateSelected"));
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please specify where do you want to change the dateformat. I didn't see any `m/d/yyyy` here.

Comment: @Boonya Kitpitak After I'm picking date at calendar. It's will show on result like this 3/1/2017. But i'm want to show like 03/01/2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User below method for parsing date... according to your date format..

```
public static String parsePickerDate(int Year, int Month, int day) {

    String sYear = String.valueOf(Year);
    String sMonth = String.valueOf((Month + 1));
    String sDay = String.valueOf(day);

    if (sDay.length() == 1)
        sDay = "0" + sDay;

    if (sMonth.length() == 1)
        sMonth = "0" + sMonth;

    if (sDay.length() == 1)
        sDay = "0" + sDay;

    return sYear + "-" + sMonth + "-" + sDay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert like as

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("5/1/12");

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
date = (Date)formatter.format(date);
```

if you want to change it for date Picker then you can use this

```
    @Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
    int dayOfMonth) {

int month = monthOfYear + 1;
String formattedMonth = "" + month;
String formattedDayOfMonth = "" + dayOfMonth;

if(month < 10){

    formattedMonth = "0" + month;
}
if(dayOfMonth < 10){

    formattedDayOfMonth = "0" + dayOfMonth;
}
searchText.setText(formattedDayOfMonth + "/" + formattedMonth + "/" + year);
}
```

Comment: I'm try to this solution. But It's not work for me.
Because, Result date format like this 1/1/2017. But i'm want to convert to 01/01/2017

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using simple date format as stated above.

Here is a tutorial that will show the difference in outputs.

https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DateTimeCalendar.html

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy", Locale.US);

    String date = outputDate.format(inputDate.parse("5/2/1993"));


} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```